Merge two lines of a file
I'm trying to modify a file in such a way that line number 10 is merged to line number 9. For instance my file looks like:
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
this is line nine
and this is line ten
i
j

And I would like a new file like this:
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
this is line nine and this is line ten
i
j

How can I merge two specific lines of a file? Also, since the file has a huge number of lines, would it be possible to avoid reading the whole file?
I tried to use echo $(cat filename) but it doesn't seem to work and it would also modify the whole file, not only lines 9 and 10.

See Merge 16 lines into one line

Try this: sed '9{N;s/\n10//}' <<<$'1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n8\n7\n8\n9 hello\n10 world\n11 foo\n'

You  question is unclear! On which base do you want to merge lines? Every 9th line? by pair? On some word or regex found? ... Or just once: One modification AT line 9??

Just once: I only need that modification once at line 9

If there are only 9 lines in the input should the output end with a newline character or a blank character or just whatever character was before the newline on the 9th input line?

You're looking for something like this:
sed '9{N;s/\n/ /}' file

sed is a stream editor used for text manipulation which executes a sequence of commands to each line of the input file. It has knowledge of two memory blocks. The pattern space is one of those and is by default printed at the end of the command sequence. Here is how it works:

begin: load the current line in the pattern space
9{...}: This means that the two commands enclosed between braces, will be applied only to the 9th line.
N: This command appends the next line of input to the current pattern space. The line is prepended with a newline character.
s/\n/ /: This s command replaces the first newline character \n in the pattern space with a space.
end: print the pattern space


@TedLyngmo I believe the 9 and 10 are the line numbers and are not part of the input.

Those lines are just numbers, sorry for the confusion. But does that code modify the initial file into a new file with the desired change?

@Urza_tron No worries. I edited your question to make it clearer. You'll have to redirect the output from oguz's sed to a file to get the new file you want: sed '9{N;s/\n/ /}' inputfile > outputfile

Thanks! What if inputfile and output files are the same? Shall I write the same filename twice or do I have to do something a bit different?

@Urza_tron you can try sed -i '9{N;s/\n/ /}' file. It works on most platforms

@Urza_tron Your question says "I would like a new file". Perhaps you should edit the question if a new file is not what you want?

Thanks everyone, it is working. I just have one last question.. is there a way to stop traversing the file once this operation has been done (or alternatively once the 10th line has been read)? It would save a looot of time since the file is pretty long.

Using any awk, this is probably what you want to cover not just the sunny day case where the input file has 10 or more input lines but also the rainy day cases of an input file with less than 10 lines or even empty (given my assumption that you'd want to output a valid POSIX text file, one that ends in a newline, without adding a trailing blank char in those cases):
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR == 10 ? OFS : ors), $0; ors=ORS} END{printf ors}' file
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
this is line nine and this is line ten
i
j

